# Bundle for Ruby 1.9 hash syntax, or way to modify existing matches?

Tags: textmate, sublimetext2, textmatebundles

I'm working with Rails and using Ruby 1.9 in SublimeText, but it does some quirky highlighting with Ruby 1.9's new hash syntax.

For example, with the following hash, which is pretty common for rails:

`<%= link_to some_page_here_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

The `class` keyword is highlighted, when it's not actually a real keyword but instead just a simple hash key. I'd prefer if it were styled as a symbol (which it is in Ruby 1.9) instead of a reserved word. This applies for the other reserved words as well, 'for', 'while', 'do', etc.

Is there a way to make this work in the existing Ruby.tmLanguage, or a tmLanguage file that already does it? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I went ahead and edited the Ruby.tmLanguage file to fix it.

You can find the definition of the reserved keywords by searching the file for `keyword.control.ruby`; the corresponding regex looks like

```
(?&lt;!\.)\b(BEGIN|begin|case|class|...|when|while)\b(?![?!])
```

The negative lookahead at the end `(?![?!])` prevents it from matching method names like `class?` and `class!` so adding a colon to the list `(?![?!:])` will also stop it matching hash keys like `class:`.

Comment: This works perfectly! I don't think I would have found that in a million years. Thanks so much for coming back and leaving the answer here, greatly appreciated.

Comment: This just made my entire week. Thanks Andy! By the way, there are a few other regexes in that file which need the same treatment. I did a search for that negative lookahead in the whole file, and added a colon to the ones where it made sense.